# boost::multi_array_ref vs. boost::multi_array&

Tags: c++, boost-multi-array

Is there a reason to prefere the usage of `boost::multi_array_ref` over `boost::multi_array&`? Why is the adapter class `boost::multi_array_ref` provided by boost at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those would be two quite different things. `boost::multi_array&` is a reference which can be bound to already existing multi array, and you can use it for indirection to a 'true' multi array container.

On the other hand, `boost::multi_array_ref` is an *adaptor* - it allows one to use it with any other block of continuous data as if it was a multi array (while in fact it is not). (I personally think this is not a great name, as it implies a reference to the container)

See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html for more details.

Comment: Do you know an example of a class etc. which needs this adapter?

Comment: @UweJ Not sure. Perhaps you can use it to access C-style arrays of array as if it was a `boost::multi_array`? Haven't tried it myself.

Comment: This is correct, it is also important to note also that in Boost.MA `multi_array` IS-A ``multi_array_ref`. Therefore a `multi_array` can be bound to `multi_array&` but also to a `multi_array_ref&`!. In this sense, taking a function argument by `multi_array_ref&` if appropriate is more general than taking the argument by `multi_array&` (i.e. simply by reference). See https://godbolt.org/z/6TEbbPce7